# Detach JPA objects with lazy initialized properties

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, transactions, lazy-loading

There are two JPA entities: User and Order with one-to-many relationship.

```
/**
 * User DTO
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8372128484215085291L;

    private Long id;
    private Set<Order> orders;

    public User() {}

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sequenceUser")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    public Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }
    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
 }


/**
 * Order DTO
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 84504362507297200L;

    private Long id;
    private User user;

    public Order() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sequenceOrder")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public User getUser(){
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

I use these entities in my service layer classes where every method runs in transaction. Everything is fine except cases when methods of service layer classes must return these entities.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Set<Order> getOrders() {
    Set<Order> orders = user.getOrders();

    return orders;
}
```

This method returns data well. But when I try access to received collection elements I catch exception: "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: package.User.orders, no session or session was closed".

So, it was excepted. I thought that detaching result will solve my problem, but trick like this

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Set<Order> getOrders() {
    Set<Order> orders = user.getOrders();

    for(Order order: orders)
        entityManager.detach(order);
    return orders;
}
```

didn't change anything :(

It doesn't matter for me will info about users attend in set of orders or not. I just want to work with this set and not going to modify it.

Can anybody help me? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This method returns data well. But when I try access to received collection elements I catch exception: "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: package.User.orders, no session or session was closed".

The error is self explaining: you are trying to load a (lazy) loaded collection but there is no active session anymore because the `User` instance is detached.

> So, it was excepted. I thought that detaching result will solve my problem, but trick like this

This won't change anything. The [`EntityManager#detach(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29) method doesn't *load* anything, it removes the passed entity from the persistence context, making it *detached*.

> It doesn't matter for me will info about users attend in set of orders or not. I just want to work with this set and not going to modify it.

You need to either make the association EAGER (so that Orders will be loaded when retrieving a User) or to use a FETCH JOIN when retrieving a user in your service:

```
SELECT u
FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.orders
WHERE u.id = :id
```

---

> Do I understand correctly that hibernate has no standard mechanism for force load all lazy associations of current object

Hibernate has a `Hibernate.initialize` method, but this is obviously not standard JPA (prefer fetch join for portable code).

> I have no way to make hibernate ignore lazy associations of current object (set them as null)

What? What do you mean by ignore? Why would you do that anyway?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to clarify two moments: Do I understand correctly that hibernate has no standard mechanism for force load all lazy associations of current object - only appropriate method or query call? I have no way to make hibernate ignore lazy associations of current object (set them as null)?

Comment: I understand that attempts to ignore lazy inits is wrong, but I have purely academic interest. For example, I got object of User class via entity manager: "User user = entityManager(User.class, 1)". At this moment "orders" property equals null because it's lazy. Is it possible to "detach" object "user" from hibernate to prevent property "orders" init during access method "getOrders"?

Comment: @mikhail `Is it possible to "detach" object "user" from hibernate to prevent property "orders" init during access method "getOrders"?` Search for "unproxy" or "deproxy" on the Hibernate forums.

Comment: Thanks again! It's exactly what I've searched!

Answer (score 1):

The LazyInitialisationException occurs because data is requested outside a transaction. If you need that data, you must request it within a transaction - in your case, this would be within the service method.

You can request the data to be loaded in several ways. The easiest:

```
for(Order order: orders)
    order.getX()
```

(where X is some property other than Id or version)

This however will load each order in a seperate query, which is slow if there are many orders. A faster approach would be to issue a query (JP-QL or Criteria) returning all orders of that user. (Edit: See Pascal's answer for a suitable query.)