# How to detach persistent attributes of a Hibernate object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an object in Hibernate with a few lazily loaded `many-to-one` columns. I don't necessarily need the object to be persisted with the database for a set of operations.

How do I directly get a object so that every time I try to access a many to one entity it does not need to lazily fetch from the database, and I can retrieve the value (doesn't matter if it is not the latest) without having a session open.

Right now I am opening the session, creating a new object and sending it for the operations to be performed.

```
// Hibernate class
public class Foo {
   private Long id;

   //many-to-one mapping
   private Bar barObj;

   //getters and setters
}
```

now whenever I call `fooObj.getBarObj().getId()` there is a proxy call to the server to fetch the value of the ID. I don't want this call to take place, and want the `fooObj` to be locally saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the 'fetch=FetchType.EAGER' annotation argument or fetch with a query where you explicily say 'join fetch barObj`. Thirdly, you can [write some code](http://candrews.integralblue.com/2009/03/hibernate-deep-deproxy/) that will achieve *deep deproxying*. This is probably the best fit for your needs, even though far from trivial.

Comment: I would like to keep the fetch type as lazy. As the records I retrieve are a lot and very few need such operations. Is there a shorter way to get just one particular object

Comment: Then use the second suggestion -- fetch using a HQL query where you explicitly state `join fetch barObj`.

Comment: That's a work around to the problem as I have many such object and there will be multiple joins I have to take care of. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hm. So you want to sometimes fetch lazily, sometimes eagerly, but don't want to specify at each fetch what to do? So you'd just like to fetch automatically on detach?

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642151/detach-jpa-objects-with-lazy-initialized-properties) which might help you. The part mentioning `Hibernate.initialize`, and, in the comments, "deproxy" or "unproxy".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - yes, it indeed sounds like a case of 'I want to eat my cake and have it too', but upvoting for the wealth of options you provided in your answer. Particularly the deep deproxying link you gave.

Comment: Deep deproxy was helpful. I am relatively new to hibernate. Doing a cover up for a friend on leave. I have just got hold on the jargons :)