# How to test a variable is lazy loaded if private?

Tags: java, jpa, testing

I am using JPA and am lazy loading a variable.  Were using method level annotations, with the variables all private.

In my automated tests I want to verify that the variable in question is not loaded until I make a call on it.  I have found references to using PersistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded method, but I can't pass it the variable directly since it's private.

I tried using my getter method to fetch the lazy loaded variable to pass to PersistenceUnitUtil, but that appears to case it to be loaded which defeats the point of the test.

Is there another way to verify that this private method was not loaded?  I suppose I could use reflection to peak at the private variable but that seems pretty convoluted, there must be an easier approach.

If relevant were using spring boot and testNG.

Comment: I don't know if it works, did you try to detach the entity and called then the getter. This way the variable shouldn't lazy loaded.

Comment: @user3584190 no I had not, mostly because I'm still new to JPA and didn't realize detaching was possible.  this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642151/detach-jpa-objects-with-lazy-initialized-properties suggests that will work though.  I'll try it out and see what happens

Comment: it's quite common and simple to use Spring's ReflectionTestUtils to do the reflection. you could also create another getter for the field, only for the test, you might need to annotate it with @transient

Comment: @MarianP Thank you for the suggestion.  I don't like hard coding the variable name with the reflection, though I don't know why that bothers me when the alternative is hard coding a method name with reflection.  I guess because the method name is at least public and thus part of our public contract.  I am interested in the getter field though.  How do you make a getter field that won't automatically load the lazy field when I run get?  I thought that was effectively automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA API PersistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded takes the ENTITY object NOT some field value, so no real idea why you say about getting the value of the field/property. So for example

```
boolean loaded = emf.getPersistenceUnitUtil().isLoaded(myEntity, "someField");
```

The javadoc of that method does not distinguish whether the "someField" is private or whatever, that is for the implementation to handle